# Allow user A to grant view permission of their node to user B

Tags: 7, users

My website users will have the ability to post pictures in a private photo gallery. I would like for those users to be able to grant "view" permissions for their private gallery to other users.

- Bob (an authenticated user, not an admin) has a private photo gallery
- He wants Dave (another authenticated user, also not an admin) to be able to view his private photo gallery
- Bob grants permission to Dave, allowing Dave to view that gallery
- Bob can revoke permission from Dave at any time

Is there a module/configuration that will this type of user-controlled granting of permissions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps consider using [Organic Groups](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) which allow users to create and control groups of users and curate content for them.

There is also [Node Access User Reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference) which is slightly more specific.

Both should work together but I think you will only need one of them for your stated needs.

Comment: Node access user reference looks like it is exactly what I need. Thank you!